# Google analytic how to decide new transactions of users

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to know a transaction is a first transaction with a user? I have searched the docs and not sure which dimension can determine this?

Comment: This is really hard to understand. You are looking at the transaction report and want to know, for any given id, if this is the first of multiple transactions, is this it ? Ideally you could give an example of what you expect your report to look like.

Comment: This is from a user, I am maintaining a existing report, I am no expert on Google Analytics, but I know how to play with query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ so for example, I can pick ga:date, ga:transactions and get transactions by date, but the user want to know for each day, how many of the transactions are new transactions, that is the first time the user has made a transaction, is that possible?